# formatDate JavaScript function only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, function, date, browser, nan

I have a JavaScript function which works without problem in Chrome, but not in other browsers such as Firefox or Safari:

```
function formatDate(date){
    var result =  date.getFullYear() + "-" + 
    (((date.getMonth()+1)<10?'0':'') + (date.getMonth()+1)) + "-" + 
    date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + 
    (date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date.getMinutes() + ":00";

    console.log("formatDate(): " + result);
    return result;
}
```

This is where the formatDate function gets called:

```
var duration = 1;
var startString = $("#inputDatetime").val();
var startObject = new Date(startString);

var endObject = startObject;
endObject.setHours(startObject.getHours() + duration);
var endString = formatDate(endObject);

setCookie("start", startString, 3600*60*24*30);
setCookie("end", endString, 3600*60*24*30);
```

Chrome Output:

```
formatDate(): 2013-11-18 17:00:00
```

Firefox Output:

```
formatDate(): NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN:00
```

The prefered output would be something like 
`2013-11-21 16:00:00`.

What do I have to change in order to get it supported in all browsers?

Comment: Works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Outputs "2013-11-15 10:55:00" for me in ie 9

Comment: I'm not sure how this could possibly return the `NaN` string you report. If you pass it something that's not a real Date instance, it should simply fail when you try and call all those (probably) non-existent methods.

Comment: MomentJS might make your life a bit easier. moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")

Comment: what does your startString look like in your FF? Seems like new Date(startString) can not parse startString into a valid date and therefor all methods you call return NaN.

Comment: [17:25:18.072] "start cookie: 2013-11-22 17:00"

Comment: Is there maybe a better way to add hours to the start date in JavaScript? I think the problem could be related to that. I also tried with moment.js, and the same happens, that means the input date object is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that only Chrome supported `new Date(startDate)`;

My solution using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
var duration = 1;
var startString = $("#inputDatetime").val();

var endObject = moment(startString).add('hours',duration);
var endString = moment(endObject).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

setCookie("start", startString, 3600*60*24*30);
setCookie("end", endString, 3600*60*24*30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var startObject = new Date(startString.replace(/\-/g,'\/'));
```